# Which ball will be first and why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

We have two slopes - and at start line we put two balls (each ball have separate slope). Questions:

1. Which ball will be first at finish line?
2. Why?

You can find answer to first question in [this movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBSRPuUibxk) - but what is the explanation of this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aware of the [Brachistochrone curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve)?

In the case of the video it's tempting to believe both balls will finish at the same time because at the end of the run they indeed have the same kinetic energy (and at equal mass, thus also equal velocity, $K=\frac12mv^2$).

However, [analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve#Analytic_solution) (and experiment) shows inclines [of descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve#/media/File:Brachistochrone.gif) that inititally have a strong downward slopes, compared to the straight 'diagonal' incline, **provide faster overall trajectories** (even though their final velocity is equal to that of the latter)

The slighly unusual left hand trajectory is a series of the former type and thus faster than the straight 'diagonal' on the right.